# Python extracting dictionary values efficiently and create html page

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, pandas

I am having following sample data from dictionary (actual data is huge)

```
{name': 'SECURITIES', 'advance': {'advances': 123, 'declines': 101, 'unchanged': 0}, 'timestamp': '09-Jan-2020 15:30:22', 'database':[{'symbol': 'ABC', 'identifier': '', 'series': 'EQ', 'open':100,'close':90,'ltp':89,'industry':"Bank"},{'symbol': 'CDE', 'identifier': '', 'series': 'EQ', 'open':120,'close':130,'ltp':125,'industry':"Bank"},{'symbol': 'EFG', 'identifier': '', 'series': 'EQ', 'open':1000,'close':1010,'ltp':1009,'industry':"IT"},..... ]'date':'1-Jan-2020'}
```

Here I want to first extract data of key value "database" and from database values select only symbol and ltp columns and create basic html page. I am using python 3.7, can you pl tell me what is the efficient way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: is that json or dictionary? it is not well-structured.

Comment: this is json data stored into dictionary

Comment: This is far too broad/vague, and likely off-topic.

Comment: ok understood, keep away html part aside how can i do extraction of database value and subvalues from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
   'name': 'SECURITIES', 
    'advance': {'advances': 123, 
                'declines': 101, 
                'unchanged': 0}, 
    'timestamp': '09-Jan-2020 15:30:22', 
    'database':[{'symbol': 'ABC', 'identifier': '', 'series': 'EQ', 'open':100,'close':90,'ltp':89,'industry':"Bank"},
                {'symbol': 'CDE', 'identifier': '', 'series': 'EQ', 'open':120,'close':130,'ltp':125,'industry':"Bank"},
                {'symbol': 'EFG', 'identifier': '', 'series': 'EQ', 'open':1000,'close':1010,'ltp':1009,'industry':"IT"}],
    'date':'1-Jan-2020'
}

df = pd.DataFrame().from_records(data['database'])
print(df)

   close identifier industry   ltp  open series symbol
0     90                Bank    89   100     EQ    ABC
1    130                Bank   125   120     EQ    CDE
2   1010                  IT  1009  1000     EQ    EFG
```

Now as far as creating the html goes, you can do the following:

```
html = df.to_html()
f = open('file_name.html', 'w')
f.write(html)
f.close()
```

and you should have a file called `file_name.html` now in your directory.

You can also look into Dash - https://dash.plot.ly/datatable
which will load up a localhost web page where you can create tables with more options.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Let me check out and also check dash.plot